Springboot - cosmosdb - API - RBAC permissions to perform action Issue
I am trying to access cosmosdb data using Spring boot using the article - Microsoft CosmosDB API
and getting error.
The Stacktrace - core - does not have required RBAC permissions to perform action [Microsoft.DocumentDB/databaseAccounts/readMetadata] on resource
com.azure.cosmos.CosmosException: {"innerErrorMessage":"Request blocked by Auth  MASKED : Request is blocked because principal [ MA-SK-ED] does not have required RBAC permissions to perform action [Microsoft.DocumentDB/databaseAccounts/readMetadata] on resource [/]. Learn more: https://aka.ms/cosmos-native-rbac.\r\nActivityId:  MA-SK-ED, Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Common/2.14.0, StatusCode: Forbidden","cosmosDiagnostics":artTimeUTC":"2024-05-14T12:34:59.579377200Z","durationInMilliSecs":26.5077},{"eventName":"received","startTimeUTC":"2024-05-14T12:34:59.605884900Z","durationInMilliSecs":15.0303}],"partitionKeyRangeId":null,"responsePayloadSizeInBytes":0,"exceptionMessage":"Request blocked by Auth  MASKED : Request is blocked because principal [ MA-SK-ED] does not have required RBAC permissions to perform action [Microsoft.DocumentDB/databaseAccounts/readMetadata] on resource [/]. Learn more: https://aka.ms/cosmos-native-rbac.\r\nActivityId:  MA-SK-ED, Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Common/2.14.0, StatusCode: Forbidden","exceptionResponseHeaders":"{Transfer-Encoding=chunked, Strict-Transport-Security=max-age=31536000, Server=Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0, Content-Location=https:// MASKED.documents.azure.com/, x-ms-gatewayversion=version=2.14.0, Date=Tue, 14 May 2024 12:34:59 GMT, x-ms-activity-id= MA-SK-ED, Content-Type=application/json, x-ms-substatus=5301}"}],"samplingRateSnapshot":1.0,"systemInformation":{"usedMemory":"24960 KB","availableMemory":"16694912 KB","systemCpuLoad":"empty","availableProcessors":16},"clientCfgs":{"id":1,"machineId":"uuid: MA-SK-ED_","connectionMode":"DIRECT","numberOfClients":1,"excrgns":"[]","clientEndpoints":{"https:// MASKED.documents.azure.com:443/":1},"connCfg":{"rntbd":null,"gw":"(cps:1000, nrto:PT1M, icto:PT1M, p:false)","other":"(ed: true, cs: false, rv: true)"},"consistencyCfg":"(consistency: null, mm: true, prgns: [])","proactiveInitCfg":"","e2ePolicyCfg":"","sessionRetryCfg":""}}}
at com.azure.cosmos.BridgeInternal.createCosmosException(BridgeInternal.java:478) ~[azure-cosmos-4.58.0.jar:4.58.0]
at com.azure.cosmos.implementation.RxGatewayStoreModel.validateOrThrow(RxGatewayStoreModel.java:504) ~[azure-cosmos-4.58.0.jar:4.58.0]
at com.azure.cosmos.implementation.RxGatewayStoreModel.lambda$toDocumentServiceResponse$1(RxGatewayStoreModel.java:365) ~[azure-cosmos-4.58.0.jar:4.58.0]
at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74) ~[netty-common-4.1.109.Final.jar:4.1.109.Final]
at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30) ~[netty-common-4.1.109.Final.jar:4.1.109.Final]
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833) ~[na:na]

POM
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.5</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
<groupId>com.example</groupId>
<artifactId>cosmosdb</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>cosmosdb</name>
<description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
<properties>
    <java.version>17</java.version>
    <spring-cloud-azure.version>5.12.0</spring-cloud-azure.version>
</properties>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.azure.spring</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-azure-starter-data-cosmos</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.azure.spring</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-azure-dependencies</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-cloud-azure.version}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>

My application.properties

spring.application.name=cosmosdb
spring.cloud.azure.cosmos.endpoint=https://cosm99995338tw8ter8w67.documents.azure.com:443/
spring.cloud.azure.cosmos.database=cosmosdb000773


spring.cloud.azure.cosmos.populate-query-metrics=true

Entity
@Container(containerName = "samplecontainer")
public class Employee {....}

Repository is normal as in the article
My cosmosdb

I am not sure of the permissions ( not mentioned in the article) , but I see my id is owner (cosmos db account IAM)
What is the problem with the example ?
Thank you

Ok resolved the issue. Unfortunately Microsoft documentation always is incomplete and full of mistakes / errors.
spring.cloud.azure.cosmos.key=sssgdgz9K###### property is also required


Thanks for bringing this to attention. Using ".key" is using Master Key authentication. Your original issue seemed to be related to Entra ID Auth using a specific Principal, was that not intentional?

@MatiasQuaranta I was trying to follow the steps , and the out of the box  example was not working. You can give a different answer i..e.  how to use entra id

Thanks for this clarification. My question was mainly aimed at understanding the reason for the initial error in order to properly update the documentation to make it easier for future users.

no problem. I also prefer without master key, but I looked at this article - https://dev.to/mkheck/cosmos-db-for-spring-developers-part-i-using-cosmos-db-as-a-sql-database-28me  and tried Set required properties

The team is working on a doc update to include both (keys and Entra ID) options as part of our documentation. Thanks for your valuable feedback.
